# How to run a function when there is a failure in web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have set up my tests to run using TestNG, and I can rerun the failed tests. However I need to configure my tests so that when there is any WebDriver exception, to run a function.

For example, if any of the following lines fail, I have a failure log in my report. But the webdriver active browser is closed and the test ends; I need to implement a function so that before the browser is closed to run a separate custom function to Logout from the application.

```java
protected void clickxxxxx() throws Exception{
    customMethods.Click(By.id("finish"));
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    customMethods.waitForWebElement(By.id("statusElement"));
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the TestNG `@After*`?

like

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterClass() {

    //logout


}
```